# Enabling Change Data Capture (CDC) for a specific DML operation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, change-data-capture

Am new to CDC.Is it possible to enable Change Data Capture for a specific DML operation(s) in SQL Server 2012? I know that by default it enables for Insert, Delete and Update. If I want to enable only for update then how can I achieve that?

Also please let me know, how CDC is better compare to Triggers?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you cannot split the operations up at the source, but you can extract only the operations you want afterwards.

You would enable the table for CDC and specify the columns you need to admin.
The output table would be cdc.{Instancename}_CT, and from this you would extract just those rows with Operations 3 & 4, which relate to the before_update (3) and after_update(4).

If you are only interested in the resultant values for any given table row, you should use net_changes.

Comment: Sorry I missed the second part of the question. The simple advantage CDC has over triggers is that they are asynchronous to the DML operation. They read from the log and not the table, whereby triggers  fire with the operation itself, thus, if anything goes awry in the trigger it can often lead to errors being raised and the need to rollback changes made.